# Is there a way to set all members of a group to be superuser in django?

Tags: django-admin, django-authentication

In Django, I would like to set all members of a group (administrators) to be superuser. Is there a way that I can do this so that new members of the group are automatically made a superuser?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this using signals. You can get the point after which a user has been added to a group and make that user a superuser if they are in the administrator group.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(signal=m2m_changed, sender=User.groups.through)
def manage_administratiors(instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, using, *args, **kwargs):
    if model == Group and action == 'post_add':
        administrators_pk = Group.objects.get(name='administrators').pk
        if administrators_pk in pk_set:
            instance.is_superuser = True
            instance.save()
```